# how can i open and close a q-popup upon clicking the q-date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar-framework

There is a date there in the below code. How to just select only the year in q-date?
I'm just hoping if I can somehow just close the div when the model or the container meets the length 4. which I've already get. but when I click the date it wont showing the q-date since I set it to false. what should I do to set it back to true?

```
<q-input
      style="width: 200px"
      outlined
      v-model="advance_search.advance_year_option_year_start"
      mask="####"
      label="Start Year"
      stack-label
    >
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer"  >
          <q-popup-proxy
          v-if="qDateClose"
            cover
            transition-show="scale"
            transition-hide="scale"
          >
            <q-date

            v-model="advance_search.advance_year_option_year_start"
            @update:model-value="closeQDate(advance_search.advance_year_option_year_start)"
            default-view="Years"
            mask="YYYY"
            emit-immediately
            minimal
          />
          </q-popup-proxy>

        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
```

**Part of JavaScript code**

```
let qDateClose = ref(true);
    
let closeQDate = (value) => {
    if(value.length == 4){
      qDateClose.value = false;
    
    }
};
```

or please suggest any alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the hint from [@Sarsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75504779/16209) and it works:

```js
const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      date: ref('2019/02/01'),
      dateClosePopup: ref(true)
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<!--
Forked from:
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/date/#example--with-qinput
-->
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
    <q-input filled v-model="date" mask="date" :rules="['date']">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date v-model="date"
                      v-close-popup="dateClosePopup"
                      @navigation="dateClosePopup=false"
                      @update:model-value="dateClosePopup=true"
>
              <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat></q-btn>
              </div>
            </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using v-close-popup

at @navigate event set it to true then @update:model-value set it to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).